# How to match the name and show details from firebase in another java file?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have ***StaffAttendanceCheckIn.Java***, if user click on the **addOnItemTouchListener** inside, i want to make it either show dialog or go to another page and show out the attendance record. For example if user clicked on the Event Name Google, it would show out the firebase record. After click inside it will show out filtering. If user choose Tuesday 06 Nov 2018, it will show out the check in  date and check in time. I'm not sure how to write after **onDataChange**

**StaffAttendanceCheckIn.Java**

```
package com.example.edward.neweventmanagementsystem;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.edward.neweventmanagementsystem.Model.EventInfo;
import com.example.edward.neweventmanagementsystem.ViewHolder.MenuViewHolder;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

public class StaffAttendanceRecordTable extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference eventInfo;
    FloatingActionButton search_item;
    RecyclerView recycle_menu;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <EventInfo, MenuViewHolder> adapter;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    private TextView EventName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_staff_attendance_record_table);

        recycle_menu = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycle_menu);
        recycle_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recycle_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AttendanceRecord");

        recycle_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        search_item = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.search_item);

        FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() ;
        eventInfo = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ListOfEvent").child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid());

        loadMenu();

        recycle_menu.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(getBaseContext(), recycle_menu ,new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {



                        mDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                EventName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RegisterEventName);
                                if(dataSnapshot.child(EventName.getText().toString()).exists()){
                                    Toast.makeText(StaffAttendanceRecordTable.this, "Got Result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    Intent intent =  new Intent(StaffAttendanceRecordTable.this, com.example.edward.neweventmanagementsystem.attendanceListMainList.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);



                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(StaffAttendanceRecordTable.this, "No Result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                    }

                    @Override public void onLongItemClick(final View view, int position) {



                    }
                })
        );

        search_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent search = new Intent(StaffAttendanceRecordTable.this, Find_Event.class);
                startActivity(search);
                System.out.println("Testing search Item");
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadMenu(){
        Query query = eventInfo.orderByKey();
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<EventInfo>().setQuery(query, EventInfo.class).build();
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<EventInfo, MenuViewHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_list,viewGroup,false);
                return new MenuViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MenuViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull EventInfo model) {

                holder.txtRegisterEventId.setText(model.getRegisterEventId());
                holder.txtRegisterEventStartDate.setText(model.getRegisterEventStartDate());
                holder.txtRegisterEventName.setText(model.getRegisterEventName());
                holder.txtRegisterContactNumber.setText(model.getRegisterContactNumber());
                holder.txtRegisterEventRadiogroup.setText(model.getRegisterEventRadiogroup());
                holder.txtRegisterEventLocation.setText(model.getRegisterEventLocation());


                holder.txtEventPrice.setText(model.getEventPrice());
                holder.txtEventCapacity.setText(model.getEventCapacity());

                holder.fileName.setText(model.getFileName());

                //Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImageToUpload()).into(viewHolder.imageView);
                //Glide.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImageToUpload()).into(viewHolder.imageView);

                Glide.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImageToUpload()
                ).into(holder.imageView);
                System.out.println(model.getRegisterEventName());
                System.out.println(model.getImageToUpload());
            }

        };
        recycle_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you said when clicked on `addOnItemTouchListener` then you want to fetch all events.

You can use this code. Little modified your code.

Using this code you will get **All Event Names** inside **Attendance Record,**

```
    recycle_menu.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getBaseContext(), recycle_menu ,new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                    DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;

                    mDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            ArrayList<String> eventNames = new ArrayList<>();

                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                                eventNames.add(snapshot.getKey());

                                //Now you have all Event Names in List
                                // you can show them in a Custom Alert Dialog
                                //Or pass it to next Activity.

                            }

                            EventName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RegisterEventName);
                            if(dataSnapshot.child(EventName.getText().toString()).exists()){
                                Toast.makeText(StaffAttendanceRecordTable.this, "Got Result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                Intent intent =  new Intent(StaffAttendanceRecordTable.this, com.example.edward.neweventmanagementsystem.attendanceListMainList.class);
                                startActivity(intent);



                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(StaffAttendanceRecordTable.this, "No Result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                }

                @Override public void onLongItemClick(final View view, int position) {



                }
            })
    );
```

Lets say you have displayed these codes in your Activity/Alert Dialog and user clicked on any event.

You can **fetch all days** inside that event using below code.

```
    databaseReference.child("clicked_item").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<String> eventDays = new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                eventDays.add(snapshot.getKey());

                //Now you have all days that exist inside Clicked Item (Google)
                //Same as previous you can show them in Alert Dialog or New Activity,

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

The Last part.. As you have all the Days and you have displayed these days to user and User clicked on any day.

Now you want to fetch **checkInDate** & **checkInTime**. you can use below code to fetch this data.

```
    databaseReference.child("clciked_Day").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String checkInDate = snapshot.child("checkInDate").getValue().toString();
                String checkInTime = snapshot.child("checkInTime").getValue().toString();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

***Hope this will help you !!***

Comment: I found your eventNames can fetch all the all the event name but seems like my code after EventName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RegisterEventName); got problem. How to amend it to get the proper event name in the recycle view after click? If user click the Google then it shpw get the event name google

Comment: didn't get you. what you want exactly?

Comment: you have already hard coded event names in your XML? that's what you're saying ?

Comment: Or I change another way to say. How can i get the only one event name if user click 1st event get 1st event name, clcik second event get second event name? Becasue currently is get all the names.

Comment: That's what i mentioned here `displayed these codes in your Activity/Alert Dialog`. you have to display all events in Custom Alert Dialog, let user to click on any event and fetch data according to that event. you can also pass the `Arraylist` to next activity and display it in recylerview and then listen for user click. On user click fetch days inside that event,, Got it ?